# Failing to load script files in target page after window.open()

Tags: javascript, html

I am using webstorm to open my webpages.

Basically, I have a customers.js that contains `window.open("../customers-form.html")`, and customers-form contains a script with `src="./scripts/customer-form.js"`.

When I open customers-form.html directly, the script runs fine, but there is a problem with accessing it through `window.open()` from the other file.

`GET http://localhost:63342/scripts/customers-form.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT:**
I noticed that the link when I am in customers.html is `localhost:63342/WDF/customers.html`, but `localhost:63342/customers-form.html` after `window.open()`. This probably is the problem, but I have no idea how this can be fixed. For some reasong, webstorm is loading customers-form.html outside of its parent folder WDF.

**EDIT 2:**
I fixed it by using `location.href = "../../WDF/customers-form.html"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was calling `location.href` (or `windown.open()`) from a javascript file, I thought that the current directory is that of the same file, not of the html document, but I was mistaken. Those calls go back to the html document.